# Why does adding an as-pattern to a working function cause compilation errors?

Tags: haskell, types, as-pattern

[Here's](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.1.0/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-Instances.html) the standard Functor instance for `Either a`:

```
instance Functor (Either a) where
        fmap _ (Left x) = Left x
        fmap f (Right y) = Right (f y)
```

adding in an as-pattern causes compilation errors when loading into GHCi:

```
instance Functor (Either a) where
        fmap _ z@(Left x) = z          -- <-- here's the as-pattern
        fmap f (Right y) = Right (f y)

Couldn't match expected type `b' against inferred type `a1'
  `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for `fmap' at <no location info>
  `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for `fmap' at <no location info>
  Expected type: Either a b
  Inferred type: Either a a1
In the expression: z
In the definition of `fmap': fmap _ (z@(Left x)) = z
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: `Either x a` and `Either x b` both have elements named `L x`, so `fmap f (L x) = L x` works. But `a@(L x)`, on the left means that `a` is identified with something of type `Either x a`. But what is needed on the right is something of type `Either x b`

Answer (score 11):

`fmap` has signature `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, i.e. it has to allow for `a` and `b` to be different. In your implementation, `a` and `b` can only be the same, because it returns the same thing that was passed as an argument. So GHC complains.

Comment: From a beginner's point of view, the standard instance also `returns the same thing that was passed as an argument`.  The difference is somewhat subtle -- at least to me.

Comment: @MattFenwick The subtle thing is that the `Left` on the left and the `Left` on the right aren't the same thing; the one on the right is more polymorphic! You might like to try writing `data Phantom a = Phantom` and comparing the types of `f a@Phantom = a` and `g Phantom = Phantom`.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that this fails because `z` represents different types on each side of the equation:

- the overall type is `fmap :: (a -> b) -> Either t a -> Either t b`
- on the left side, `z :: Either t a`
- on the right side, `z :: Either t b`

It seems that `Left x` is allowed to have multiple different types in the same equation, but `z` is not.

This implementation also fails, apparently for the same reason:

```
instance Functor (Either a) where
        fmap f (Right y) = Right (f y)
        fmap _ z = z          

Couldn't match expected type `b' against inferred type `a1'
  `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for `fmap' at <no location info>
  `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for `fmap' at <no location info>
  Expected type: Either a b
  Inferred type: Either a a1
In the expression: z
In the definition of `fmap': fmap _ z = z
```

Comment: Nothing surprising since the type of `z` is fixed to be `Either t a`. On the other hand `Left :: forall a b. a -> Either a b` and because of that `Left x :: forall b. Either t b`, which allows you to pick any `b` you want.

Comment: @Vitus good point, I'm so used to Haskell's implicit forall's and type inferencing that those differences are usually invisible to me ...

Answer (score 2):

If you specialize the signature of `fmap` to `Either l`, you get:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Either l a -> Either l b
```

This means that the `Left r` that you are pattern-matching on the left-hand side of your case statement must have type `Either l a`.  However, you can't return it as is, because you have to return an `Either l b`.  This requires re-wrapping the left-hand value in a new `Left` so that the compiler can infer that it is returning a newly minted `Either` that might have a different type for the `Right` value.

Answer (score 2):

For the `Either a` instance, `fmap` has the following type:

```
(i -> j) -> Either a i -> Either a j
```

In this equation:

```
fmap _ (Left x) = Left x
```

the second argument is known to be of type `Either a i` and to have matched the pattern `Left x`. We take the `x` out, and apply `Left` to it to get the result of `fmap`.

The trick is that the `Left` on the left side of the equation is not the same thing as the `Left` on the right side! On the LHS `Left` is this constructor:

```
Left :: a -> Either a i
```

Whereas on the RHS the `Left` is this constructor:

```
Left :: a -> Either a j
```

The RHS `Left` used in the pattern wouldn't have matched the type of `fmap`'s second argument `Either a i`, and the LHS `Left` doesn't construct values of the type needed as `fmap`'s result `Either a j`.

So there's no way to use the same `Left` for both things, semantically speaking; you have to construct a new `Left x :: Either a j` containing the `x` found in the `Left x :: Either a i`. *Operationally*, the Haskell implementation may or may not represent those two terms identically, and may or may not be able to share a single in-memory representation of two values with different types, and may or may not be clever enough to optimise away the construction of a new value that would be represented identically to another value it already has on hand. But those implementation issues are distinct from what the program *means*, and the type-checker's role is purely concerned with meaning.